# Add unique items to .txt file from the list in Python

Tags: python, list, loops, file, dictionary

I have a list of dictionaries such as

```
item_list = [
    {'Name': 'Bob', 'Surname': 'Smith'},
    {'Name':'Alice', 'Surname':'Black'},
    {'Name':'Maggie', 'Surname':'McLaren'}
]
```

As well, I have .txt file with existing lines in dictionary format (as my list):

```
{'Name': 'Jared', 'Surname': 'Long'}
{'Name': 'John', 'Surname': 'White'}
{'Name': 'Bob', 'Surname': 'Smith'}
{'Name': 'Julia', 'Surname': 'Moor'}
```

And I need to add all the unique items from my list to this file, so at the end I want to have:

```
{'Name': 'Jared', 'Surname': 'Long'}
{'Name': 'John', 'Surname': 'White'}
{'Name': 'Bob', 'Surname': 'Smith'}
{'Name': 'Julia', 'Surname': 'Moor'}
{'Name':'Alice', 'Surname':'Black'}
{'Name':'Maggie', 'Surname':'McLaren'}
```

I tried to do it with loops, but nothing helped, as a result I have duplicated lines. Also, my file opens in 'a+' mode. Could somebody help with it?

Comment: Please update your question with your code which doesn't work.

Comment: you will need to read the file, merge the content with your item list and then append/overwite it.

Comment: Please edit to show your code, so we can see what may be going wrong

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would solve your problem this way:

```
import json

f = open(..., 'a+')
to_add = [
    {'Name': 'Bob', 'Surname': 'Smith'},
    {'Name':'Alice', 'Surname':'Black'},
    {'Name':'Maggie', 'Surname':'McLaren'}
]

existing = set()
f.seek(0)
for line in f:
    line = line.replace("\'", "\"")
    v = frozenset(json.loads(line).items())
    existing.add(v)

for name in to_add:
    v = frozenset(name.items())
    if v not in existing:
        f.write(json.dumps(name) + "\n")

...

f.close()
```

The solution uses `sets` for their fast lookup operation. I also replaced your single quotes with double quotes for it to be valid JSON.

Comment: This decision didn't work for me. maybe the problem is that I need to have my items in `to_add` as list, and I don't have any idea how to convert this list into kind of json object

Comment: @stupid_beaver It does not matter whether `to_add` is a `list` or a `set`. You can just replace my `to_add` with yours. By the way, since you don't know about sets, read up on them, trust me.

Comment: ok, but still this code doesn't work, I get error as TypeError: unhashable type: 'dict'

Comment: @stupid_beaver I probably fixed it. Does it work for you?

Comment: still not really, it writes duplicates to the file anyway. I thought that the problem is in quotes, because I have single quotes in my list, and at the end python prints all the items with double quotes. However, if I run the code 2x and more, I have more and more duplicates

Comment: @stupid_beaver Alright, I believe I fixed the problem. I tested it myself now, so it should be working.

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```py
from ast import literal_eval

item_list = [
    {"Name": "Bob", "Surname": "Smith"},
    {"Name": "Alice", "Surname": "Black"},
    {"Name": "Maggie", "Surname": "McLaren"},
]

out = {d["Name"]: d for d in item_list}
with open("input.txt", "r") as f_in:
    for line in f_in:
        d = literal_eval(line)
        out[d["Name"]] = d

with open("output.txt", "w") as f_out:
    for d in out.values():
        print(str(d), file=f_out)
```

The result is `output.txt`:

```py
{'Name': 'Bob', 'Surname': 'Smith'}
{'Name': 'Alice', 'Surname': 'Black'}
{'Name': 'Maggie', 'Surname': 'McLaren'}
{'Name': 'Jared', 'Surname': 'Long'}
{'Name': 'John', 'Surname': 'White'}
{'Name': 'Julia', 'Surname': 'Moor'}
```

Comment: That's might be a great solution, but I need to open my file in `a+` mode and have to use only one file